# Ordenar un String Alfabéticamente C#

Tags: c#, string

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

¿Como ordeno un string Alfabéticamente en C#?

**Ejemplo:**

Entrada

```
hola so
```

Salida

```
ahloos
```

**Código:**

```
string cadena;

Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cadena: ");
cadena = Console.ReadLine();

ORDENAMIENTO(linea);
```

Intenté hacerlo por método burbuja pero el string(linea) no me deja sobreescribir(set) el caracter (ERROR cadena[i] = cadena[i+1]), es sólo de escritura y no sé como implementar la propiedad para poder escribir sobre el string.

Cualquier ayuda/comentario es de gran ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Y qué buscas en el caso donde hay mayúsculas y minúsculas en la cadena. ¿Buscas un orden lógico que no tome en cuanta si es mayúscula o minúscula? Eso cambia la respuesta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solución usando el método [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) de `Linq`:

```
string cadena;

Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cadena: ");
cadena = Console.ReadLine();
string ordenado = new String(cadena.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray());
```

---

Para aclarar algo mas lo que preguntas (por si quieres ordenarlo manualmente), efectivamente no se puede acceder a las posiciones de un `string` en modo escritura. En ese caso lo que puedes hacer es convertir tu `string` en un array de caracteres, ordenarlo como quieras, y posteriormente convertirlo a string de nuevo:

```
char[] cadenaArray = cadena.ToArray();
//Ahora puedes ordenar usando cadenaArray, podrás hacer cadenaArray[i] = cadenaArray[i+1]
//Cuando esté ordenado, lo conviertes en cadena usando el constructor de String
string ordenado = new String(cadenaArray);
```

Comment: ¿Y en Visual Studio hay alguna setencia parecida a aOrdenar?

Comment: @byte96 eso ha sido un fallo mio, es el nombre de tu cadena. Miralo ahora que lo he editado